# updating a list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to write a program that will:

1. Take a `list` at random from `self.population` then sample three values from this list.
2. Take another `list` from the `self.population` and sample three values from that.
3. Concatenate these two sets of three.
4. Remove all previous values from my list `self.population`
5. Add my new lists until I have 20 lists in the list `self.population`.

This is what I have so far:

```
def crossover(self):
    for x in range(0,20):
        z=random.choice(self.population)
        y=random.sample(z,3)
        x=random.choice(self.population)
        w=random.sample(x,3)
        v=y+w
        for individual in (self.population):
            self.population.remove(individual)
            #print(self.population)
        self.population.append(v)
        print(self.population)
```

Comment: sorry the code has not come out correctly I will retype

Comment: When you say you want to have "20 lists in `self.population`" what does that mean? Do you want to repeat `v` 20 times?

Comment: Hi!  I want to repeat the process 20 times until I have 20 new lists in the list self.population.

Comment: Do you want every 20 times to come from the original `self.population`? As it is currently written you are replacing it on the first loop

Comment: See my updated answer, I think this does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're altering a list while iterating over it. That's a big no-no. The standard workaround is to iterate over a *copy* of the list, e.g.

```
for individual in self.population[:]:
    self.population.remove(individual)
```

However, since you're just wanting to empty the list you can do this in one line:

```
del self.population[:]
```

*Note: You can also use `self.population = []`* although this changes the list object.

However, following your updated comments it appears as though you don't need to delete the list at all. You are trying to create a *new population* so we can make a `list` variable to hold it, and leave the original population alone until we're done. The following code accomplishes this:

```
def crossover(self):
    new_population = []

    for x in range(0,20):
        z=random.choice(self.population)
        y=random.sample(z,3)
        x=random.choice(self.population)
        w=random.sample(x,3)
        v=y+w

        new_population.append(v)

    self.population = new_population
    print(self.population)
```

Note that the new variable `new_population` is used to store the new lists until the loop is complete, then assigned over the original `self.population`.

Comment: i've just tried this and what I get is just one long list, when what I was hoping for is a list of 20 different lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the 'individuals' of your list, then why don't you do:

```
self.population = []
```